# Cross-compiler: linker failed during make all-gcc on macosx

Tags: c, macos, operating-system

I am following this [wiki.osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) tutorial on making a cross-compiler. I am on MACOSX. Everything up to the point of `make all-gcc` in the build-gcc directory works. The error I get is:
`Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: "_host_hooks", referenced from: c_common_no_more_pch() in c-pch.o toplev::main(int, char**) in libbackend.a(toplev.o) gt_pch_save(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o) gt_pch_restore(__sFILE*) in libbackend.a(ggc-common.o)                                                                       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64`

I can't find other people getting this error, any help is appreciated. And I don't know if it's related to my OS i'm using.